# DDD - How do you create a new instance or load the aggregate root?

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

After starting using ddd in a project i have the following architecture :

- domain model which contains my aggregate root (AR), my entities and my value objects
- repository interface (implemented in the infrastructure part)
- application services to create, delete and update the AR. The application services used to update the AR work this way : find the AR from an ID in the database, call some methods, then save it in the database

Nb: i have only one AR because it is supposed to be a microservice and i only talk about the "command" side here.

I need 2 ways to instantiate the AR :

- one when calling the application service to create the AR from inputs
- one when retrieving the existing AR from the database, i don't really want to do all the checks

In the first case i need to create an id, do some check, etc.
In the second case I just want to recreate the AR from the data contained in the database.

How/where am i supposed to do that?

For the creation from input, i can do it in the application service like that (it is a simple example) :

```
public class CreateUser {

  private final UserRepository userRepository;

  public User execute(String name) {
    User user = new User(UUID.randomUUID(), name);
    return userRepository.create(user);
  }
}
```

For loading the AR from the database, i can either :

- user the same constructor doing some validation
- create a new one without validation (i don't really like the idea of having a constructor in the AR bypassing all the validation)

Any ideas on how to do this elegantly?

Comment: Is it a spring project?

Comment: Yes it is a spring project!

Comment: I'm not sure this has to do with the technology at all. Don't create aggregate roots. Instead, you should load your aggregate by it's identity. If it exists, you return the state you were able to load. If it does not, then you initialize a default state. Then you apply your command and the aggregate should be able to tell you whether your command is valid.

Comment: For example i start my application with an empty database and i want to create a user. How can i do that without creating an AR ? I understand that i can then retrieve it by its id and modify it later but how does it work before that?

Answer (score -2):

You are wrong in the concept of creating a new instance of the aggregate using a constructor when you load it from the database. You don't have to call any constructor nor factory nor validate any fields. Just get it from the repository with a getAggregateOfId method which returns the aggregate already constructed with the state stored in the database.